# Date calculation error(JS)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have repo method that return values from db

Here is code

```
 public List<Logging> GetDriving()
    {
        using (TraxgoDB ctx = new TraxgoDB())
        {

            var items = ctx.Logging.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Position).AsEnumerable().Select(

                x => new Logging
                {
                    Longitude = x.Longitude,
                    Latitude = x.Latitude,
                    Speed = x.Speed,
                    CurrentDateTime = x.CurrentDateTime.Date

                }
            ).ToList();

            return items;
        }
    }
```

In js i need to hide markers on heatmap where CurrentDateTime isn't == time in input.

So like this I show all markers

```
function getDriving() {
var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
$.getJSON(url,
    function (data) {
       $.each(data,
            function (i, item) {
                marker.push({
                    'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                    'map': map,
                    'weight': item.Speed,
                    'radius': 10,
                    'date': item.CurrentDateTime
                });
            });
        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(marker);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
    });
```

};

And like this I do filtering

```
$('#filter').on('click',
   function () {
       heatmap.setMap(null);
       var startValue = $('#startDate').val();
       var filtered = [];
       $.each(marker, function (i, marker) {
           var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
           var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
           var valDate = new Date(startValue);
           if (markerDate.getTime() === valDate.getTime()) {
               filtered.push(marker);
           } else {
              console.log('marker date is', markerDate.getTime(), 'valdate is', valDate.getTime());
           }
       });
       var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(filtered);
       console.log(pointArray);
       heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
           data: pointArray
       });
       heatmap.setMap(map);
   });
```

But in log I see that filtered don't have values in it.

But why?

I have in input `13/11/2017` and in database I have `2017-13-10 18:50:46.0000000` so it may be equal.

Where is my mistake?

Thank's for help.

Here is console log for `markerDate`

[image]

And here is screen for `valDate`

[image]

But why it invalid if I write `console.log(startValue);` I have this `13/11/2017`

Comment: What does `var markerDate` and `var valDate` return (use `console.log()` inspect the output)

Comment: I think `marker.date` is not what you think it is

Comment: I edited my post @StephenMuecke

Comment: I edited my post @JaromandaX

Comment: Well what is the value of `startValue`? (I'm guessing its not in `MM/dd/yyyy` format). You indicated that the value in the input is `10/11/2017`, but that will not result in `InvalidDate`, however a value of (say) `13/11/2017` would if your using Chrome

Comment: I edited post

Value in input is 13/11/2017 

dd/MM/yyyy @StephenMuecke

Comment: That is not a valid date because dates by default are `MM/dd/yyyy` format. If you want to enter dates in that format then you need to build the date value yourself in javascript (or use a library such a [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Note also that if you were using FireFox or IE, then you would not get `InvalidDate` , but instead would get a completely different date from what you entered which would make your calculation wrong anyway (I'll find a link that explains it later)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158847/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-s-e).